# Call procedure using anonymous block in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure, anonymous

I am fairly new to PL/SQL but have been reading up on it and have used some templates, including some which I found from here.

What I want to do is to write an anonymous block to call some procedures which wrere written earlier in a sql developer project. I have attempted it but it isn't running properly. It returns an error of "Error starting at line : 2 in command " and then reports a "closed connection."

This is my attempt:

```
DECLARE
    P_USER_NAME VARCHAR;
    P_DEBUG_FLAG  VARCHAR;
    P_DEBUG_FIELD VARCHAR;
    P_DEBUG_VALUE VARCHAR;

BEGIN

    schema.package.procedure(
        OutParam1, OutParam2, OutParam3, OutParam4);

    dbms_output.put_line('OutParam1: ' || P_USER_NAME);
    dbms_output.put_line('OutParam2: ' || P_DEBUG_FLAG);
    dbms_output.put_line('OutParam3: ' || P_DEBUG_FIELD);
    dbms_output.put_line('OutParam4: ' || P_DEBUG_VALUE);
END;
/
```

And these are the procedure I want to call:

```
   PROCEDURE CLEAR_DEBUG (P_USER_NAME IN VARCHAR2);

   PROCEDURE WRITE_DEBUG (P_USER_NAME     IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_DEBUG_FLAG    IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_DEBUG_FIELD   IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_DEBUG_VALUE   IN VARCHAR2);

   PROCEDURE READ_DEBUG (P_USER_NAME    IN     VARCHAR2,
                         P_REF_CURSOR      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END P_DEBUG;
```

Comment: i think your problem is with VARCHAR, it should be VARCHAR2(n), where n is the size of the variable

Comment: you want to call another oracle procedure from this block ?

Comment: @davegreen100 it still returns the same error when i change it to varchar2(10) for example. Moudiz, yes I want to test that the procedures in the second block of code are being called ok. they are in another class. How can I do this and have it run successfully?

Comment: @paul check my answer is what you need ? add command `exec` and the name of the procedure

Comment: You seem to be calling the procedures right. But in your code you might need to change the name of the parameters to the ones you declared:     schema.package.procedure(    P_USER_NAME,    P_DEBUG_FLAG , P_DEBUG_FIELD,    P_DEBUG_VALUE);

By the way, it should not be very different from calling dbms_output.put_line(); another procedure in the dbms_output package

Comment: @paul - you changed the declaration of all four local variables in your anonymous block to `varchar2(10)`? What is the full error message you get? Can you show the actual procedure call, since you're currently showing a obscured version that doesn't match any of the definitions you provided or your local variable names, and implies you're calling something that has OUT parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more errors in your code:

1. declare the variables properly - VARCHAR requires length constraint
2. OutParam1, OutParam2, OutParam3, OutParam4 are not declared - use the declared variables as arguments instead, beware of the variables passed as arguments must have the same data type
3. I expect you wanted to call `P_DEBUG.WRITE_DEBUG(P_USER_NAME, P_DEBUG_FLAG, P_DEBUG_FIELD, P_DEBUG_VALUE);`